# broken packages after running sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, ubuntu, elementary-website

After running sudo-apt-get update i got this:

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable InRelease                                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable InRelease                                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release                                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release                                     
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_GB           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_GB             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                      
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                      
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_GB                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/justsomedood/justsomeelementary/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/justsomedood/justsomeelementary/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, I got this "Partial Upgrade" bug, I'm unsure what caused it, maybe some broken packages.

Please help

I'm running Elementary OS Freya 0.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem since few weeks ago, and it is due to this repository: http://ppa.launchpad.net/justsomedood/justsomeelementary. It looks like the repository has just disappeared. If you check the the launchpad's  address http://ppa.launchpad.net/justsomedood/justsomeelementary/ubuntu/ you gonna find the message 404:

Not Found
The requested URL /justsomedood/justsomeelementary/ubuntu/ was not found on this server.

That's why I have the repository disabled for the moment, waiting its came-back.

Edited:
**To disable the repository.**
Software Center > (menu) Edition > (button) Sources > (new window - 2 tab) Other Sources > Look for *"http ://ppa.launchpad.net/justsomedood/justsomeelementary/ubuntu/"* and unchecked the box. Don't forget to save.

Edited 2:
Has been confirmed that the developer took down the repository but it's **temporally**. That's due to he was getting a whole lot of dependency errors when trying to build the latest packages.

Comment: Please add how you have disabled the repository...